# How to deserialize JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I have found lots of online tutorials but all of them are deserializing JSON strings into objects or lists of objects.

I just have a web service which returns either 1 or 0 as JSON.

So it prints something like:

```
""\"0\""
```

Or:

```
""\"1\""
```

How can I deserialize a simple JSON like that into a string?

Comment: So you have a string `input` that contains `"0"` or `"1"` and you want a string `result` that contains `"0"` or `"1"` depending on the input?

Comment: Technically this is not valid JSON according to the RFC spec.

Comment: No I have a JSON like this: ""\"0\"" or ""\"1\"". Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @ChaosPandion So you think the web service should just return 1 or 0 as a string? Not encoded as JSON?

Comment: @Richard Knop: the web service should return a [JSON Object](http://www.json.org/) or a [JSON Array](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: Ok. Somebody just write it down as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [RFC4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627) a valid JSON string is defined as either a JSON object or a JSON array. Your web service should return something similar to this.

```
{ "Result": 0 }
```